# Trying to figure out Error when attempting to add a text box in a MS Visual Studio C++ Dialog

Tags: c++, dialog

For Microsoft Visual Studio C++ Community 2019,

I'm trying to add a textbox into a Dialog box I made. I'm having trouble adding a textbox into it by right clicking on the new dialog box and using "Add variable". Keeps saying - "Did not find a dialog class with the specified ID 'IDD_DIALOG1'. I tried adding the class name in the Dialog properties under the "Class Name" field. But that did not work.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the "Edit control" in the toolbox. the youtube video:  VC++ / C++ MFC tutorial 1: Creating a Dialog box for user input
will be able to assist you further. Cheers.